# Apache has `network` instead of `httpd`. Also uses `systemctl` instead of `chkconfig`. Why? (EC2 Linux AMI 2)

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, apache-2.4, httpd

I am learning about networking so I'm following a book.
Currently, I am setting up a web server inside my EC2 instance.
When I ran `sudo chkconfig --list httpd` as the book suggested, I got an error saying

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-1-10 ~]$ sudo chkconfig --list httpd

Note: This output shows SysV services only and does not include native
      systemd services. SysV configuration data might be overridden by native
      systemd configuration.

      If you want to list systemd services use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.
      To see services enabled on particular target use
      'systemctl list-dependencies [target]'.

error reading information on service httpd: No such file or directory
```

So I tried `sudo chkconfig --list` which gives me this

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-1-10 ~]$ sudo chkconfig --list

Note: This output shows SysV services only and does not include native
      systemd services. SysV configuration data might be overridden by native
      systemd configuration.

      If you want to list systemd services use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.
      To see services enabled on particular target use
      'systemctl list-dependencies [target]'.

netconsole      0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
network         0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

It seems that the error happened when I was expecting

`httpd 0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off`

but instead I got

`network  0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off`

This seemed very weird to me and I could not find out why. Hence, I want to ask

### Question

1. Why is `httpd` not being called `network` here? I've made LAMP instance before (with different command) and actually never had a trouble.
2. Why is `systemctl` being used not `chkconfig`?

P.S.

#### Version information

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-1-10 ~]$ yum list httpd
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
Installed Packages
httpd.x86_64                         2.4.39-1.amzn2.0.1                         @amzn2-core
```

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out!

It was because I was using **Amazon Linux 2 AMI (HVM), SSD Volume Type**. 
I solved it by using **Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03.0 (HVM), SSD Volume Type **

It seems that the use of chkconfig has been replaced by systemctl in Linux 2 instance.

Comment: Be aware that Amazon Linux 1 and your book are obsolete. You'll have catching up to do when you start trying to use current operating systems.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes I am aware of that. It’s sad to see someone downvote this without a reason or duplicate somewhere, since I actually offered a valuable solution.